# Spaceship failing with `This request is forbidden for security reasons - The API key in use does not allow this request`

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, fastlane

I ran `fastlane spaceship` to enter the [Spaceship](https://spaceship.airforce/) playground. Then I logged in with an Apple ID that has App Manager access (to all apps).

Found a build and ran `build.submit_for_testflight_review!`

Then I got this error:

> Spaceship::AccessForbiddenError: This request is forbidden for security reasons - The API key in use does not allow this request

The [docs](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/docs/Authentication.md) say:

> Login with API tokens is not supported yet as API access is not generally available

Why is it talking about an API key in the error? I do have an api key and it only has developer access, but I'm only setting that api key up in a fastlane lane, which I'm not calling here because it's just the Spaceship playground. If it is using that API key somehow, how can I swap it out?

([Posted this on the Fastlane discussion forum](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/discussions/19427) but no one answered yet so I thought I'd try here)

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem, and if yes, how? Thanks!

Comment: I posted an updated in the linked discussion forum post

Comment: OK, I'll check that out, thanks!